# Jboss 7 CLI - unable to start interactive mode but gui mode works

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7, jboss-cli

The jboss CLI does not seem to start when it was working a few hours back. I was using the CLI to setup JNDI data source and setting up two way SSL for certificate based authentication using the elytron framework.

```
kerth@ubuntu:~/jboss-eap-7.1/bin$ ./jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] 
kerth@ubuntu:~/jboss-eap-7.1/bin$ echo $?
0
```

Starting the Jboss CLI with -c or --connect also does not enter the interactive mode. It just exits with a exit code 0 without any error.

```
kerth@ubuntu:~/jboss-eap-7.1/bin$ ./jboss-cli.sh -c
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] 
kerth@ubuntu:~/jboss-eap-7.1/bin$ echo $?
0
```

The gui mode of the CLI(`./jboss-cli.sh --gui`) however **works**. Not sure if i am missing something.

Enabling the Jboss CLI logging does not have any ERROR or WARN logs.

Using a freshly downloaded installation zip of jboss 7.1 and trying to start the CLI also does not work(No environment variables set). A freshly downloaded Jboss 7.2 CLI however works.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I am using the default interfaces,
Jboss version - 7.1 update 4,
OS - Ubuntu 18

Comment: That's very strange. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle JDK - 1.8.0_191

Comment: That is very strange. I've got no idea what it could be. I definitely cannot reproduce it on Fedora 29.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thanks for your time. I have no clue either. I also tried with OpenJDK 8 with the same results. I am guessing an operation through the CLI has made a change in the kernel due to which i am unable to use the CLI in interactive mode. A colleage of mine uses Ubuntu 16 and Oracle JDK 8 also has the same issue where only the gui mode works

Answer (score 0):

Either your code pasted is wrong or I think you are missing "connect" before you connect you can't work with the CLI.

- Execute the cli with ./jboss-cli.sh
- type "connect" withouth the quotation marks.
- Execute the desired commands
- type "exit"

or alternatively you could do ./jboss-cli.sh **-c** to connect as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but what i pasted is correct. It won't start the cli and it keeps exiting with exit code 0. 'Connect' is used when you enter the CLI but it won't enter the CLI mode in the first place.

Comment: What is the error you get if you use `./bin/jboss-cli.sh -c`? That should definitely work assuming JBoss EAP is started.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I have added more info to my question above